# Are Overwatch sprays language settings specific?

Tags: overwatch

Take the WoW Legion pre-order bonus spray for example which reads "Ihr wisst nicht was Euch erwartet" in my game since language is set to German.

If I get queued with players from different regions and plant my spray, would it show up to them in their respective language or would it read the German text for them too?

Comment: My initial thought is no, as I have played with many foreign people and I didn't even know sprays could be in other languages. That might however be because they use image sprays

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just did go in a game to make a quick test with English players (as I am a French one). I used the spray "Merci" (which means "Thanks"). While it appeared as "Merci" for me and another French player, it appeared as "Thanks" for the English ones.

So the sprays are definitely translated from one language to another.

Now, it doesn't apply to all the sprays, because some characters have sprays linked to their own background (their country), and so the language on those sprays is kept whatever which country you are coming from. But you can recognize those easily, as they are not translated in your own language either (except if the character is from your own country of course).

Comment: That is somewhat sad.  It would be pretty cool if the sprays stayed in their respective languages.  That way, there would be a somewhat global feel to each match/game, instead of a generic "I am playing with people in my region" feeling.   But oh well, Blizzard knows all........

Comment: @NZKshatriya I'm assuming that the Thanks spray that Isuka is talking about is the Hearthstone-style speech bubble with that word inside. In that case, it makes sense to translate the text to each player's language, since there are 4 speech bubble sprays (Thanks, Oops, Well Played, and Sorry) that are all identical other than the text. If they stayed in their own language, players wouldn't know which was was being used.

Comment: I imagine the various versions of a single spray or voice line share the same resource ID. When a player sprays, the game tells the rest of the players "player x put resource y in location z", and what you see is dependent on what resource y means to your client. If you have the French client, you might see "Merci" where the English clients will display "Thanks"

Comment: @NZKshatriya That's generally not the way you'd program though. Generally there's a locale setting for each player and the resource being identified will be displayed in that locale. Also it makes little sense to display generic messages like "thanks" in other languages that the player might not recognize. It's not as much for the "feeling that he's playing in the same region" as for comprehensibility.